# Dynamic Entity pickup for logging

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, logging

Need advice, I am trying to develop a generic logging api(data persistence will be by jpa with hibernate) . This logging framework is for logging request/response of multiple microservices so data should be logged in multiple tables hence multiple entity beans. I need to find a way to pickup the right entity bean for the corresponding service to persist.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the criteria to find the entity bean?

Comment: every single service will have its own table to log, so we need to find the associated entity